# Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

when i try to generate singend apk its show apk singend failed

bulid.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fma.airhorn"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
message falied

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

  > Keystore file 'E:\Android\jre\jre\bin\air horn relase' not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s

Comment: `air horn release` not fount in the specified URL

Answer (score 0):

You might have misplaced the path to the `keystore.jks` file.

Check your `keystore` path. find the location where the `keystore` path was generated for the first time. check at C:\Users.android